# Working with query strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just integrated a single sign-on provider into my application, which is now sending a query string parameter when it redirects back to the requested page, which causes the page to not load. The way it is set up is:

- I have a controller at localhost/AppName/Controller, whose Index method requires [Authorize]
- Forms authentication redirects to the SSO
- SSO redirects to localhost/AppName/Controller/?ticket=stringvalue
- Page doesn't load (browser has a "cannot display the web page" message); removing the ?ticket business makes the page load.

My Index method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string ticket)
```

which I thought would accept the query string parameter. I am using the default route configuration, that is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    // Route name
    "Default", 
    // URL with parameters
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Comment: does it work if the full url is used - i.e. /Home/Index?ticket=`ticket`?

Comment: When you remove the `?ticket` business, is the `Index` action still executed?

Answer (score 1):

There is clearly something screwy about this - because there is no good reason why this should not work.

I'll bet if you take off the [Authorize] attribute you'll find that it works with the `?ticket=[value]` bit in the Url.

If so, then I reckon Forms auth is getting stuck in a redirect loop (and the browser, after a while will simply refuse to continue) - I think it's not treating the current `User` as `IsAuthenticated=true` and so redirects to your SSO.  The SSO says that the user is logged in and so redirects with the ticket parameter - ad nauseam.

You can debug this simply with the VS debugger and breakpointing your action method.  Equally debugging at the Http level is often easier: download [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) and then hit your site using the special name http://ipv4.fiddler instead of http://localhost once it's up and running.

There must be more to your code that you haven't included, though - presumably somewhere you have code that intercepts the `ticket` and sets the user to be authenticated before the MVC action method kicks in?  If so - I reckon that's failing.

Comment: Since I can't submit my own answer, I'll just throw this in here: I was dumb. Had the server name set as 'localhost' instead of 'http://localhost'.

Comment: Ah - now I would *like* to say that I've never done that before...  but I can't ;)